# How to duplicate a geometry node layout as unique node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

i have a node i want to copy and change some values.
Unfortunately it always makes an instance and any adjustment to the duplicated is applied to the original.

My instance (to instance on point) in the node layout is always a grid-node.

The layout is animated..

Comment: ok i found it... just had to copy and paste the grid-node inside the layout ;)

Comment: Could you post that as an answer below with a short explanation of the solution please? Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and UI

Answer (score 2):

In modifiers stack, you can click on a number to make a single-user copy:

[image]

You can do the same inside the Geometry Nodes Editor's header:

[image]

And you can do the same on a group you add inside your node layout:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just duplicate the node elements you want to adjust inside the whole duplicated node layout, and then delete the old one.

For example the grid node where you wanted to adjust the values in the copied node layout for a different object.

Just hitting <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> (duplicating the grid node) and deleting the old grid node. Then it becomes a unique one.